# ruby call optional parameter

Tags: ruby

I have the following method:

```
def method(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
  puts a
  puts b
  puts c
  puts d
end
```

Is there a way to output like this without checking the variables nullity? When I call the method like:

```
method(5,7)
=> 5
=> 2
=> 7
=> 4
```

Comment: how is it supposed to know you omitted b and d as opposed to c and d, say?

Comment: Have you considered using keywords arguments: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments
(otherwise no, there is no way)

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are taken in order so when you have this method:

```
def method(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
  puts a
  puts b
  puts c
  puts d
end
```

The call:

```
method(5,7)
```

means: a = 5, b = 7, c = 3 (default value), d = 4 (default value)

There is no way to specify a parameter without specifying all the others.

If you want to be able to specify the parameters, an alternative is to use an hash for all your params:

```
def method(options)
  a = options[:a] || 1
  b = options[:b] || 2
  c = options[:c] || 3
  d = options[:d] || 4
end
```

You can then make calls such as:

```
method(d: 5, c: 7)

=> 1
=> 2
=> 7
=> 5
```

Comment: your second suggestion is deprecated by keyword arguments.

Comment: you are right - same principle but more modern approach

Answer (score 1):

As Taryn East mentioned in his comment, since Ruby 2.0 you can use keyword arguments to achieve what you want to do. You just have to define your method a little bit different:

```
def method(a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4)
  puts a
  puts b
  puts c
  puts d
end
```

Then, you can call it specifying the parameters you want to set by name, leaving the others to their default value:

```
method(a:5, c:7)
=> 5
=> 2
=> 7
=> 4
```

As another benefit, it improves readability and doesn't leave the reader guessing about the meaning of the passed values.

- [Ruby 2.0 documentation for keyword arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments)

Answer (score 0):

One of the popular options would be to redefine your method with so called "named parameters". Well, they are not really named parameters, they're just a hash params with some syntactic sugar.

```
def method(args)
  args = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}.merge(args)
  args.each { |key, val| puts val }
end

method(c: 30, a: 10)

> 10
> 2
> 30
> 4
```

Comment: What is the benefit over using keyword arguments here? Your code seems to do the same and more complex to me.

Comment: For one, it works in Ruby 1.9. Two, it is still commonly used pattern in popular open source libraries for compatibility and the OP would benefit learning this syntax.

Comment: Okay, I think it would improve your answer if you mention that.